# How can I remove the green strip in the GreenDroid theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, greendroid

I'm using the [Green Droid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library in my application to implement quick actions. I don't need the action bar present in the theme. How can I remove the green strip at the top which is used for action bar? I've tried editing the theme but nothing seems to be working. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your `onCreate()` method:

```
getActionBar().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.tutos-android.com/introduction-greendroid)

it shows how to use the greendroid library to do what you need and other basic task. Although its in french but if you view it in google chrome, it should translate it for you.